# How to collect SSH logs from Azure VM and push it to log analytics workspace

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics-workspace

I want to store all SSH logs (user logging/logout) to a Log Analytics workspaces

Details of my environment :

VM : OS - Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS

Connected with exiting Log Analytics workspace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the scenario on my end and was able to push VM auth logs to Log Analytics : -***

> I want to store all SSH logs (user logging/logout) to a Log Analytics
> workspaces

I created one Linux VM with OS- Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS

> Azure VM’s login logs are not collected on Azure’s end as that is a
> VM’s data plane operation. But you can see VM’s user login details
> inside your Linux VM and send these Logs to Log analytics workspace.
> the same operation can be done for your on prem local Linux machine.

Check User ssh details in VM by using command :-

```
last
```

[image]

```
 lastlog
```

[image]

All these logs are saved in auth.log file in Linux VM inorder to inspect the auth.log file you can run the below command :-

```
tail -f -n 100 /var/log/auth.log
```

In order to send this auth.log file to Log analytics workspace, There are 2 methods :-

**Method 1)**  :-  **With Legacy Log analytics agent -**
Go to >
*Log analytics workspace > Agents Management >Linux Servers > And run the below given command in the Linux machine to install the Log analytics agent on the Linux VM*.

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Microsoft/OMS-Agent-for-Linux/master/installer/scripts/onboard_agent.sh && sh onboard_agent.sh -w <workspace-id> -s <key> -d opinsights.azure.com
```

[image]

Our Linux VM is connected to the Log Analytics Workspace and you can check the logs :-

[image]

You can also enable specific syslogs by clicking on
*Legacy agent management > syslogs > Add facility and select specific logs from your Linux VM:*-

[image]

> Note- Method 1 utilizes Log analytics agent will be deprecated in
> 2024, Its recommended to Migrate to Azure Monitor Agent.

**Method 2 :-**  **Using Azure Monitor Agent**  **[Recommended] -**

1. Azure Monitor Agent can be installed directly from  *VM left pane > Extensions + applications*  like below :-

   [image]
2. Another method is via  **Azure Monitor Agent**:-  **[Recommended]**

I created a Data collection rule to collect the required logs from Linux VM to Log analytics Workspace :-

[image]

Create an Endpoint > Select Next > Collect and Deliver > Add Data Sources > In Data source type > Select Linux syslog > and select LOG_AUTH > refer below :-

[image]

Select Log analytics Workspace in the destination -

[image]

Create the Data collection Rule :-

[image]

Now, You can enable Azure Monitoring agent by visiting :-  *Search for Monitor on Azure Portal > Virtual Machines > Select your Virtual Machine > Enable Azure Monitoring agent.*

[image]

Now,  *Select Azure Monitor agent > Click Configure*:-

[image]

Now, Wait for some time for the Auth logs to reflect which has details on the User Log in and Log out :-
Go to:-
*Monitor on Azure Portal > Logs > Select syslog table*

[image]

Your VM Logs will be stored here.

**Method 3) [Optional]**  Use Diagnostics settings
You can enable diagnostics settings and use Azure Monitor agent for Linux to store your VM logs inside a storage account. This method is not recommended if you already have Log analytics in place to avoid duplicate and reduce cost.

*Select your Linux VM > Diagnostics settings > Pick one storage account to store your VM logs.*

[image]

Diagnostics settings will store the auth logs in the selected storage account :-

[image]

Click Save.

**Reference:-**

- [Enable VM insights in the Azure portal - Azure Monitor | Microsoft

  Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/vm/vminsights-enable-portal#enable-azure-monitor-agent-on-monitored-machines)
- [Collect Syslog data sources with the Log Analytics agent in Azure

  Monitor - Azure Monitor | Microsoft

  Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/agents/data-sources-syslog)